# Best method to show all pages in site collection?

Tags: web-part, site, pages

Using Sharepoint 2013 I'd like to show all pages in a site collection in a categorized view on the homepage. Would like to be able to filter on this view as well. Is this possible? I've been working with the content search wp but it's not giving me what I want yet.

Thanks in advance,
Josh

Comment: would displaying a list view web part of the Pages library be enough?

Comment: @Ryan: It'd only show pages in the current web

Comment: Jim is right - I need to see pages from all subsites within the collection, so everything is in a separate list. To be more specific, what I'm doing is an extranet where each customer has their own subsite. But internally we need to be able to see everything at once. Alternatively we could put everything in one list, but that'd be over 7000 pages in one list, at about 4GB of data. I'm also concerned about segregation of data and security in that model...

Comment: I'm thinking I have to create a webpart with SPSiteDataQuery. See: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx)